# Session State Server vs Custom Session State Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, architecture, asp.net-4.0

I have been tasked to scale out the session for an application.  From my research the most obvious choice is to use the State Server session provider, because I don't need the users sessions to persist (SQL Server Session provider)

About the app:

- Currently using InProc session provider
- All objects stored in session are serializable
- All objects are small (mostly simple objects (int, string) and a few simple class instances)

Before I dive head-first into the IT side of things and with the ability to provide a custom session provider with ASP.NET 4, should I even consider a custom session state provider.  Why or why not?  Are there any "good" ones out there?

Thanks!
  User feedback:

- Why are we using session: persistence of data between postbacks (e.g. user selections)
- How: user makes a selection, selection is stored. User leaves a page and returns, 
  selections are restored.  etc. etc.
- Will be creating a web farm

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing *why* and *how* you use session, but also consider Server AppFabric (formerly Velocity).

Comment: What do you mean "how"? I thought AppFabric is for caching.

Comment: Well, session state is 'caching' between postbacks.

Comment: `Session` *is* a cache. It's different than the regular `Cache` insofar as it's user-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend that before you look in to scaling out session that you first evaluate whether session was even needed in the first place.

Session variables are serialized and deserialized for every single page load whether the page uses that data or not. (**EDIT**: Craig pointed out that you have some level of control over this in .net 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior.aspx  However, this still has drawbacks, see comments to this answer.)

For single server instances this is okay as you are just pulling it from the local memory of your web server.  The load on these apps tend to be pretty small so caching user specific information locally makes sense.

However, as soon as you move storage of session to another server you have increased the network requirements and page load times of your application.  Namely, every page will result in the session data to be moved from the remote server, across the network wire, and into memory of the web server.

At this point you have to ask yourself: is the load to pull this information from the database server directly as necessary more than pulling it from the session server every single time?

There are few instances where pulling it from the database server as needed takes longer or results in more traffic than grabbing it from a remote session server.

Bearing in mind that a lot of people set up their database server(s) to also be session servers and you start to see why use of session doesn't make any sense.

The only time I would consider using session for load balanced web apps is if the time to acquire the data exceeded a "reasonable" amount of time.  For example, if you have a really complex query to return a single value and this query would have to be run for lots of pages.  But even then there are better ways that reduce the complexity of dealing with remote session data.

Comment: "Session variables are serialized and deserialized for every single page load whether the page uses that data or not." This is the default, true, but it's wrong as a general statement, and if performance is a concern you *should* set the behavior you want explicitly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior.aspx

Comment: @Chris: Def. food for thought and something I've mulled over countless times.  Given the information in my question, however, how would you 'evaluate' the need for session in my case?  What do you propose?

Comment: @Craig: There are two problems with that.  First, it's an attribute that overrides inherited classes.  So you have to set this on a page/page or controller by controller basis.  Second, if you have it on then the page is still going to get ALL session data whether it used those particular items or not

Comment: @subt13: I would store those selections in a table in the database.  If it is supposed to persist, then this would allow you to control how long it really is persisted and allow you to keep those selections even after they have logged out.

Comment: I don't argue that doing this right is hard. Remember the joke: "There are two difficult problems in software: Cache invalidation and naming things." But "don't cache" isn't alway an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Chris - I must admit that I've never considered that possibility.

Comment: @Chris - would everything be stored in the database, or would a session "id" be stored on the client?

Comment: @subt13: If you have some key like a user id, then store it in the database associated with that.  If you don't, then send a cookie down to the client with some type of generated id.  You might even have a field called "LastAccess", which is updated each time the data is accessed.  Then you could set something to clear out the table if the last access was over a week or so.

Comment: @Craig: I did not say "never cache" However, you should understand exactly what benefit, if any, you are getting from the type of cache you have selected.  If you aren't getting any benefit then what's the point in adding that complexity?

Comment: @Chris: Of course. That's true of *any* performance optimization, no?

Comment: I have decided to try this approach.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by "scaling" session storage.  If your simply talking about session state performance, your not going to beat the in-process session state provider.  Switching to the State Server provider will actually make things slower -- due to the extra overhead of serializing and transferring objects across process boundaries.

Where the State Server can help you scale, is that it allows multiple machines in a load balanced web-farm to share a single session state.  It is limited by machine memory, however, and if you will have lots of concurrent sessions you may want to use the SQL Session State provider.

For the most performance in a web farm, you can also try using AppFabric as was previously suggested.  I haven't done it myself but it is [explained here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx)

[Also, here's a link for using Memcached as a Session State provider](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/).  Again, I haven't used it, so I can't offer an opinion on it...

EDIT:  As @HOCA mentions in the comments, there are 3rd party solutions if cost isn't an issue.  One I've heard of (but not used) is [ScaleOut SessionServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/scaleout-sessionserver/).

Comment: State Server also has the limitation of not being able to distribute session state across multiple State Servers.  While SQL Session State provider could potentially scale in a cluster of SQL Servers, both its slow performance and high cost make it a less than ideal option.

Comment: +1 - for web farm you have to use out of process session state. Depending on your existing infrastructure setting up SQL state might be the easiest to start with. If you load becomes too high for single SQL you can either split session state between multiple servers (using partitionResolverType  -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx).

Comment: In the past we've implemented our own custom Memcached Sesssion State provider to some success.  The pro's are speed and cost.  The con's (3 years back) was reliability.  I'm sure there have been plenty of updates to both Memcached and its .NET interface since we implemented it, so this may be an option worth considering if cost is a concern.

If cost isn't a concern, evaluate 3rd party solutions as they might provide better reliability and support.

Answer (score 5):

I've provided some links you can read up on on properly scaling session using the state server.

Useful links from Maarten Balliauw's blog:

- http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-%28aspnet_state%29.aspx
- http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning.aspx
- http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning-using-State-Server-Load-Balancing.aspx

My State Server related projects:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/p2pstateserver.aspx (latest code at https://github.com/tenor/p2pStateServer)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/stateserverfailover.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: These seemed helpful, so I put them into your answer for you. :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks, I've been a lurker for a long time :)

Comment: Great links.  Especially the first one.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise against the use of session state, regardless of the provider.

Especially with your "very small objects" use viewstate. Why?

1. Scales best of all. NOTHING to remember on the server.
2. NO worries about session timeout.
3. No worries about webfarms.
4. No worries about wasted resources for sessions that will never come back.

Especially in ASP.NET 4 viewstate can be very manageable and small.

Comment: Sessions were created for a reason:) Viewstate is page specific.  Increasing viewstate slows down the page. Viewstate is unreliable.  Other than that I agree.

Comment: What do you mean 'viewstate is unreliable?' Both viewstate and session were created to 'fake' statefulness in web pages. I only posted because I have had nothing but heartache with session state and anything you can do to avoid it would be good.

Comment: Ya, I hate session too, but it's a necessary evil.  Everytime I try to use viewstate I get errors.  I suppose that is just user-error.

Comment: Session is just a user-specific cache. Despite the fact that people often misuse it, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with that. OTOH, viewstate has its own problems.

Comment: I think -2 is enough already... While your post makes good point on using view state it is generally not a replacement for Session state. It is very hard to keep view state across pages and requests. I.e. it gets lost on GET requests and can not be used during 302 redirects.

Comment: @subt13: I disagree that session is a "'necessary' evil"  In particular with the necessary part.  There are very few instances where the value session provides exceeds it's problems. If this is a limited lifetime app that will never run on more than 1 server, then fine.

Comment: @Chris - To clarify, in the context of my question, it is a necessary evil. In other applications it may not be.

Comment: @subt13: you might want to read my answer here.  All of that data you are storing in session is loaded for every page, even the ones that don't use those values.  That's a lot of traffic and there are better ways.

Comment: I gave this post +1, because it provides a new and uncommon viewpoint, that has its own merits - provided that you are experienced and exactly know what you are doing. I think that your post would be **more acceptable** by others if only you'd say "try/verify/thinkof/etc" instead of imperative "don't do it". In the imperative forms, it is dangerous to fresh web developers. It still is important viewpoint, please reword it!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Thank you for the suggestion. I will do just that.